# scheme delete all repeated elements from a list except the last one

Tags: scheme

I am learning scheme and as an assignment I have done a bunch of functions as invert a list or concatenate both of them; all recursively and not using append or reverse built-in ones.

My homework is write a function which receives as only argument a list and returns other list where all repeated elements are gone except the last one. And I can use an auxiliary function.

My idea was to accumulate seen elements into an accumulator hosted by an auxiliary recursive function. As base casa I have if the list is null, concatenate the first element and save it on the accumulator; if not, take the first element and save it on the auxiliary one too, but eliminate all the elements and cons a new list of it, where previously you have inserted the original first list element:

Concatenate to lists

```
    (define (concatena L1 L2)
    (cond
        ((null? L1) L2)
        (else (cons (car L1) (concatena (cdr L1) L2)))
    )
)
```

Eliminate all L1 elements from a list L2

```
(define (elimina L1 L2)
    (cond ((empty? L2) L2)
          ( (equal? (car L2) L1) (elimina L1 (cdr L2) ) )
          (else (concatena (list (car L2) ) (elimina L1 (cdr L2) ) ) )
    )
)
```

My approach:

```
(define (repetidos L1)
    repetidos-recorre(L1 '())
)
(define (repetidos-recorre(L1 acc))
    (if (null? (cdr L1))
        ( concatena( list(car L1) acc ) )   
        ( concatena ( ( car L1 ) ( cons( elimina( list( ( car L1 ) acc ) ) ) ) ) ) 
    )
)
```

As I realized I should use some way to know if the actual parsed elements already exists on the accumulated one I developed the function:

```
(define (miembro L X)
    (if (null? L)
        #f
        (if (eq? (car L) X)
            #t
            (miembro (cdr L) X)
        )
    )
)
```

And I tried roughly:

```
(define (repetidos L)
    (repetidos-recorre L '()
    )
)
(define (repetidos-recorre L acumulado)
    (if (null? L)
        acumulado
        (if (miembro acumulado (car L) )
            ( repetidos-recorre (cdr L) (concatena ( elimina (car L) acumulado ) (car L)   )   ) )
            (repetidos-recorre (cdr L) (concatena (car L) acumulado))
    )
)
```

And I ended in a point where I am stuck because I do know this code is misfunctioning becauser I haven't tested those two repetidos functions. I know all the auxiliaries ones function correctly and I understood them but I need help to solve this last one assignment, or at least somebody who says me how to rething this problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi enoy, it's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "all repeated elements are gone except the last one." Can you add a few examples to show how the function should behave?

Comment: You want to remove runs or all elements. eg. what will be the result of the list `'(1 a a 2 a)`.  `(1 a 2 a)` or `(1 2 a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `miembro` is correctly implemented, you don't need to use `elimina`, or `concatena`. A better approach would be:

```
(define (repetidos L)
  (repetidos-recorre L '()))

(define (repetidos-recorre L acumulado)
  (if (null? L)
      acumulado
      (if (miembro acumulado (car L))
          (repetidos-recorre (cdr L) acumulado)
          (repetidos-recorre (cdr L) (cons (car L) acumulado)))))
```

Also, instead of nesting `if`s it's better to use a single `cond`, but I'll leave it as-is for now. This is how it works:

```
(repetidos '(1 a a 2 a))
=> '(2 a 1)
(repetidos '(1 a 2 a))
=> '(2 a 1)
(repetidos '(1 2 a))
=> (repetidos '(1 2 a))
```

Notice that the elements appear in reversed order, that's because we're `cons`ing elements at the head of the list. If the order matters, then we have to use `concatena`, but bear in mind that it'll be a less efficient solution:

```
(define (repetidos-recorre L acumulado)
  (if (null? L)
      acumulado
      (if (miembro acumulado (car L))
          (repetidos-recorre (cdr L) acumulado)
          (repetidos-recorre (cdr L) (concatena acumulado (list (car L)))))))
```

As you can see, the order is preserved:

```
(repetidos '(1 a a 2 a))
=> '(1 a 2)
(repetidos '(1 a 2 a))
=> '(1 a 2)
(repetidos '(1 2 a))
=> '(1 2 a)
```

Comment: Thank you Oscar Lopez for your time I understood your solution and it was easier than I thought, except the cause because of the cons list is reversed. Finally I caught it and you helped me!